# in Rails3 beta 4 where is the code that gets executed when you type 'rails server'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm tracing my way through the source code and can't seem to find where the command "rails server" would be for a generated app.  Where is it?  Also is there  some way I can track down these things in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2 there was the `script/server` ruby script local to an application. In Rails 3, it appears they detect when they are inside a rails application path and have global scripts for all applications.

If your ruby install location was `/ruby191`, it would be in: `/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb`

Comment: Thanks. I understand how I missed it now.  cli.rb' exec_script_rails calls script/rails in your rails application directory which requires 'rails/commands'.